# Webserver running PHP app very slow - IIS 8 - Windows Server 2012

Tags: php, mysql, iis, webserver, windows-server-2012

I have a PHP app running in Windows Server 2012, my problem is that when there are 5 or more users using the same page it takes a long time to load the data.

For example I have this page `example.com/section_one.php` and if that amount of users are at same time making a request the page takes like 40 seconds to 1 minute to load and then display the info at same time as well.

In this page I have few queries to a `MySQL` tables I checked already that every table I use have their indexes, I optimized the queries and everything is fine with the tables, they have no too many records, maybe like `50,000` , and for me seem stupid that just 5 users can make slow this site, the webserver has enough resources to handle this amount of users and much more.

This is a dedicated server from GoDaddy and they don't give me support because they say is dedicated and I'm responsible for what happens with the server, it could be a kind of configuration I'm missing or that I need?

I'm pretty sure that is not my code and the tables, other things is that someday there was an update on my websever from Windows I think and change the interface of Plesk but I did notice that when try to loggin to `PHPMyAdmin` it takes like 3 to 5 minutes and before that update (no idea which one) everything was fine, I think it could be my database server but not sure how to figure out this, before I have permission to do any kind of change in `MySQL` and after that I cannot make any changes because I have no permission but this is not the problem for now.

Is is possible to know if is my mysql server?  or find the problem?

With one user it takes like 1 second to load, with 2 users like 10 seconds, with 3 like 25 seconds and it keep doing this depending on the amount of users

NOTE: I never have this problem before, I have been working with many webservers but with Apache, this is the first time I work with one using Windows Server and never have this kind of issue with my apps.

`MySQL 5.1 Server 5.1.73`

`phpMyAdmin 4.6.6`

`PHP 5.4.12`

Comment: Manually execute the queries in terminal or phpmyadmin console using `[EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/explain.html)`. Its very useful for discovering bottlenecks in SQL Queries

Comment: My second guess is: Make sure no debugging tool (like *XDEBUG*) is activated during recent update. xdebug is in real word time consuming & seriously slows down php web apps.

Comment: @BehradKhodayar thanks for your help, how can I check that tool? on the server or with PHP?